# Capacitance of a single conducting sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, electrostatics, capacitance, conductors

we were taught (very recently) in school, that the capacitance of a conducting sphere is $4\pi\epsilon_0R$ where $R$ is the radius of the sphere. we were told that the derivation of this would simply be to divide the charge $Q$ of a sphere and the potential due to the charge $Q$ at the surface of the sphere. however, after I did a bit of digging myself, I came across various definitions of what capacitance actually is. Most of them described it as the ratio of the charge stored as a result of a voltage being applied and the actual voltage applied itself.

here's where I'm confused, if we're considering the charge stored to be caused (not sure of the correct term) by the potential difference applied, doesn't the derivation I was given make no sense? If we're considering the voltage applied to be caused due to the charges on the sphere, then taking that very same charge as being caused by the potential (that it caused) seems to run into a paradox of some sort.

Don't know if what we've been taught is wrong, or if there's something that I'm missing that would make the derivation make more sense.

Comment: In physical "laws" expressed as mathematical equations, any variable can be dependent on the others. The experiment you're doing decides which one.

Answer (score 2):

Capacitance is usually defined for a system of two conducting plates much closer to each other than to other objects. The two-plate system is, as you know, called a *capacitor*. [In electrical engineering the two-plate system is by far the commonest context for using the notion of capacitance.] For such a system, we define capacitance, $C$ by
$$C=\frac{\text {magnitude of charge on inner surface of either plate}}{\text{pd between plates}}$$
It doesn't matter whether you think about the charges on the plates as arising from applying a pd between them (say from a battery) or you think about applying charges to the plates and getting a pd between them as a consequence. Note that the definition of $C$ doesn't favour either viewpoint. We shall be using the second one – for convenience.

So what about the 'isolated' conducting sphere? I prefer to regard it as a two-plate system: two concentric spherical shells with the outer one expanded indefinitely. We can then use the definition of capacitance just given.

You might object: but there is no outer sphere! It doesn't matter, because a charged inner sphere will induce opposite charges on its (distant) surroundings, in total of equal magnitude to its own charge. The induced charges might as well be on an indefinitely expanded outer spherical shell (radius $r_{out}$, say).

The pd, $\Delta V$, between the shells is the work done per unit charge taking a test charge from the outer shell (charge $-Q$, say) to the inner shell (charge $Q$), so, using Gauss's law and symmetry,
$$\Delta V=\int_{r_{out}}^{r_{in}}-E_r dr=\int_{r_{out}}^{r_{in}}-\frac Q{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2} dr= \frac Q{4\pi \epsilon_0} \left(\frac 1 {r_{in}}-\frac 1{r_{out}}\right)$$
But $\tfrac 1{r_{out}}=0$ because the outer shell is expanded indefinitely.

You will now see where the $4\pi\epsilon_0 R$ has come from.

Comment: do we take the magnitude of charge on plates to be the total charge on the plate, or only the charge that's causing the potential difference? why?

Comment: $Q$ is the magnitude of the charge on one of the plates; so in this case it is the magnitude of charge on the conducting sphere. If we put this charge on the sphere, then we can say that $Q$ is the charge that causes the pd between the sphere and a spherical conducting shell at infinity. Alternatively if we connected a battery with  a potential difference, $V$, between the sphere and the shell, we could say that $V$ causes the separation of charges, so that there are charges $+Q$ and $–Q$ on the sphere and the shell.

Comment: I'm asking about a situation where two plates that were charged to different magnitudes of charge, were brought close together, not all the charge on either plate would cause a potential difference right?

Comment: "I'm asking about a situation where two plates that were charged to different magnitudes of charge..." You must remember that each plate has two faces separated by metal. The faces of the plates facing each other will have equal and opposite charges. It is these charges that give rise to the potential difference.

Comment: I applied Gauss's law and symmetry to the case of parallel plates A and B carrying total charges $Q_A$ and $Q_B$. This showed the charges on the inner (facing) faces of the plates to be $±\tfrac 12(Q_A-Q_B)$, and the charges on their outer faces to be $\tfrac 12(Q_A+Q_B)$. So if the capacitance is C, then  $\tfrac 12(Q_A-Q_B)=C\ \Delta V$.

Comment: For a conducting sphere of radius $r_{in}$ carrying a charge of $Q_1$ separated by an evacuated gap from a concentric spherical shell carrying a charge $Q_2$ we find (very easily) that all its charge, $Q_1$ resides on the outer surface of the inner sphere (even if it is hollow), and that charge $-Q_1$ is induced on the inner surface (radius $r_{out}$) of the outer sphere, leaving $Q_2+Q_1$ on the outer surface of the outer sphere. The pd between the spheres is found as in my answer, with $Q=Q_1$.

Comment: In the light of your probing questions, I've modified the definition of capacitance that I gave in my answer. I'd bet that you won't find the modified version in any textbook!

Answer (score 1):

$\text{capacitance},\,C = \dfrac{\text{charge stored},\,Q}{\text{potential difference between the plates},\,V}$

How the potential difference got there is immaterial what is important is the charge which is stored in the capacitor and the potential difference between the plates of the capacitor.
You could say that the charge stored in the capacitor is changed and the potential difference across the plates then changes to a particular value or you could say that a potential difference is applied across the plates and the charge stored in the capacitor then changes to a particular value.

The charge and the potential difference go "hand in hand", they are proportional to one another, when one changes then so does the other in proportion.
One could have brought a charged rod up to the sphere and that would have raised the potential of the sphere or one could have connected a voltage source to the sphere and that would have increased the charge on the capacitor.

For the isolated sphere, the sphere is one of the plates and the other plate is assumed to be infinitely far away.